# Excel VBA to find href in HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm writing a macro to do the following:

1. Pulling info from various spreadsheets
2. Assign necessary info to variables
3. Open website
4. Login to website
5. **Click "Start" Button [current problem]**
6. Enter variables into form
7. Submit form

I need to click a button that says "Start" that links to a monthly form I need to fill out. This button links to a different page each month but the URL is similar, always includes "surv/questionnaire/" then a string of 6 numbers.

I guess I need to either find a way to click this start button or pull the href by looking for "surv/questionnaire/*" however I'm very new at working with HTML so maybe I'm way off.

Relevant VBA code:

```
Dim IE As Object
'launch internet explorer, navigate to website
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https://respond.fakewebsite.net/surv"
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 530
    .Height = 800
    .Width = 1200
    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With

'login to website
If IE.LocationName = "Surv: Welcome" Then
    IE.Document.getelementbyid("username").Value = "fakeuser"
    IE.Document.getelementbyid("password").Value = "fakepass"
    IE.Document.Forms(0).all("submit").Click
    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End If
```

So that code brings me right up to the point where I need to click the start button.

Relevant (I think) HTML:

```
<div class="dashboard_header">Survey Tasks <span style="color:#fff;font-size:small;">(Total Forms: 1)</span></div>

<div id="inner">
<table class="survey_tasks">
<tr>
  <th width="">Form</th>
  <th width="">Action</th>
  <th width="">Status</th>
  <th width=""><abbr title="File Number">FN</abbr></th>
  <th width="">Ind <br />Category</th>
  <th width="">Hist<br /> Data</th>
  <th width="">View/Print<br /> PDF</th>
</tr>



<tr>
  <td>1.</td>

  <!-- Action Buttons -->
  <td>
    <a class="dashboard_button" href="https://respond.fakewebsite.net/surv/questionnaire/13524">Start</a>
  </td>
```

I've changed some information above to remove the exact website and some other login information in the VBA but that last line of HTML includes the link I'm trying have the macro launch before entering the variables into the form. I've also tried using the function proposed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206910/excel-vba-how-to-copy-href-from-html-by-referencing-the-class-name) but cannot get that to work either. Looking for either guidance on how to properly use that solution or possibly another solution that's better suited for this problem.

Comment: Try IE.Document.getelementsByClassName("dashboard_button")(0).click

Comment: I hate that it was that simple....I'll see myself out now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors):

```
 IE.document.querySelector(".dashboard_button[href='https://respond.fakewebsite.net/surv/questionnaire/13524']")
```

[image: CSS query]

The "." stands for className and so the above is saying find the element with className `dashboard_button` containing href="https://respond.fakewebsite.net/surv/questionnaire/13524"